# MySQL pivot con 2 tablas no agrupa bien

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

> Necesito que me ayuden a agrupar correctamente un select pivot. Hice la consulta guiándome de algunos videos pero no me sale como deseo.

Estoy haciendo una especie de registro de asistencia con dos tablas: "personas" y "asistencia". Solo registro la hora de llegada de cada persona de acuerdo a la fecha.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y el resultado de la consulta sale así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

los nombres se repiten y no se agrupan bien, quisiera que salga solamente los 6 nombres que tengo en la tabla "persona" en cada fecha con su respectivo horario de entrada.

Aquí dejo el código:

```
SELECT per.nombre,
CASE WHEN asis.fecha LIKE '%14%' THEN asis.hora_entrada END AS '14',
CASE WHEN asis.fecha LIKE '%16%' THEN asis.hora_entrada END AS '16',
CASE WHEN asis.fecha LIKE '%17%' THEN asis.hora_entrada END AS '17',
CASE WHEN asis.fecha LIKE '%18%' THEN asis.hora_entrada END AS '18'
FROM asistencia asis
INNER JOIN personas per
ON asis.dni_persona=per.dni_persona
GROUP by asis.fecha, per.nombre, asis.hora_entrada
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No agrupes por fecha ni hora, selecciona la función de totales que te permita quedarte con la hora (o fecha) que prefieras por cada usuario: `MAX()`, `MIN()`, `AVG()`, `COUNT()`, ...

```
SELECT nombre,
  MIN(IF(DAY(fecha)=14,hora_entrada,NULL)) `14`,
  MIN(IF(DAY(fecha)=16,hora_entrada,NULL)) `16`,
  MIN(IF(DAY(fecha)=17,hora_entrada,NULL)) `17`,
  MIN(IF(DAY(fecha)=18,hora_entrada,NULL)) `18`
  FROM asistencia
  JOIN personas USING(dni_persona)
  GROUP BY 1;
```

Para este dataset de muestra:

```
CREATE TABLE personas(
  dni_persona int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  nombre varchar(31)
  );
CREATE TABLE asistencia(
  dni_persona int,
  fecha date,
  hora_entrada time,
  FOREIGN KEY(dni_persona) REFERENCES personas(dni_persona)
  );
INSERT INTO personas (nombre) VALUES
  ('Karina'),('Leonor');
INSERT INTO asistencia (dni_persona, fecha, hora_entrada) VALUES
  (1,'2022-08-14','18:12:03'),
  (1,'2022-08-16','20:11:03'),
  (2,'2022-08-14','18:11:50'),
  (2,'2022-08-16','20:11:35');
```

Con tu consulta se obtendría esto:

```
+--------+----------+----------+------+------+
| nombre | 14       | 16       | 17   | 18   |
+--------+----------+----------+------+------+
| Karina | 18:12:03 | NULL     | NULL | NULL |
| Leonor | 18:11:50 | NULL     | NULL | NULL |
| Karina | NULL     | 20:11:03 | NULL | NULL |
| Leonor | NULL     | 20:11:35 | NULL | NULL |
+--------+----------+----------+------+------+
```

Y, con lo que te planteo, esto otro:

```
+--------+----------+----------+------+------+
| nombre | 14       | 16       | 17   | 18   |
+--------+----------+----------+------+------+
| Karina | 18:12:03 | 20:11:03 | NULL | NULL |
| Leonor | 18:11:50 | 20:11:35 | NULL | NULL |
+--------+----------+----------+------+------+
```

Espero que sea lo que buscabas. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: muchas gracias amigo.. sí, se solucionó mi problema.. no entiendo aun que pasó en esa consulta, pero sí obtuve lo que quise. Gracias crack.

Comment: Al agrupar por varios criterios, te hace un grupo diferente por cada criterio que cambia. Por eso sólo puedes agrupar por nombre, no por fecha, ni hora